# Exchange 2010 PowerShell snap-ins

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2010

can anybody tell me where I could possibly find the PowerShell snap-ins for Microsoft Exchange 2010.
Of course I could just install Exchange 2010 management tools on my machine but I'd rather not for the sake of a smaller footprint etc. ;-)

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exchange 2010 EMS is using PowerShell remoting (no more snap-in loading). You don't have to install the Exchange 2010 management tools on your machine, with PowerShell 2.0 (with remoting enabled) you can load the commands into your local session (aka implicit remoting):

PS > $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://Exchange1/Powershell
PS > Import-PSSession $session

Now you can call any Exchange cmdlet from your local session.

Comment: Thank you, Shay.
Last night I found out about implicit remoting. Works well :-)

Comment: There is a performance penalty by using remoting since the IIS process on the server serializes all data to XML. With large jobs you'll see CPU spikes in IIS. That said, this is still the best option as the 2010 snap-ins are not officially supported by Microsoft. I've come across specific defects when using the snap-in that did not exist while using remote powershell.

Comment: Agree. Unfortunately, using the snap-ins is not supported by Microsoft. That said, I don't like the IIS end point either, we don't have full power over it as it runs in RestrictedLanguage mode!